# Making a POST call using Fetch in ReactJS (With header and Request Body)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I'm a complete novice to any sort of coding in general.

I am trying to consume this API exposed by a third party vendor. These are the details of the call.

URL for the API would be http://(HOST_IP):(HOST_PORT)/midsizeable/HJK/CheckerRun

```
 - Request Headers :
servicename:login  
frontofficeid:Checker 
id:Mobile
language:1 
Content-Type:application/json 
loginid:SYSADMIN1

Request Body: 
{  "data" : 
  {  "attributes": 
     {    "loginId": "SYSADMIN1", 
          "password": "abcd1234", 
           "pmuv": "RTY" 
}  
}
}
```

Here's what I've tried :

```
 componentDidMount(){
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('Accept' ,  'application/json');
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type' ,  'application/json');
    myHeaders.append('servicename' ,  'login');
    myHeaders.append('frontofficeid' ,  'Checker');
    myHeaders.append('id' ,  'Mobile');
    myHeaders.append('language' ,  1);
    myHeaders.append('loginid' ,  'SYSADMIN1');

    const myInit = {
      method : "POST",
      data : {
        attributes: {
          loginId: "SYSADMIN1",
          password: "abcd1234",
          pmuv: "RTY"
        }
      },
      headers: myHeaders
    };
    var url="http://<HOST_IP>:<HOST_PORT>/midsizeable/HJK/CheckerRun"

    var myRequest = new Request(url)
    fetch(myRequest, myInit)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((jsonObject) => {
      console.log("BODY ")
      console.log("This is Obj" , jsonObject)
        this.setState({
          message : jsonObject.id,
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });


  }
```

While this is able to run, I am getting an Error 500(Internal Server Error).  Along with I am catching a:

> **"SyntaxError: Unexpected token j in JSON at position 0"**

I know it is not an internal server error, as when I run this command using curl on the linux server, It gave ran correctly.

I've searched quite a bit but am not able to find the error anywhere.
Please help in constructing the API call.

Comment: I guess `<HOST_IP>:<HOST_PORT>` will be a different origin. Does your API have CORS enabled?

Comment: Yes, It does have cors enabled. I believe there is something wrong with the way I am constructing the API call.

Comment: Alright. It might be that you have to stringify your object into JSON. `data: JSON.stringify({ ... })`

Comment: @Tholl You are right, By adding the following tags, my call has worked : 

body : JSON.stringify({ data : {blah blah } })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn the object you use in the body of request into a JSON string.

```
const myInit = {
  method: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    attributes: {
      loginId: "SYSADMIN1",
      password: "abcd1234",
      pmuv: "RTY"
    }
  }),
  headers: myHeaders
};
```